# Roots of a integral having upper bound as variable

Tags: calculus

[image]

We are given above the graph of $f(x) = x \sin x$. Define $G(x) = \int\limits_0^x f(t) dt $. It is clear that since $G( \pi ) > 0$ and $G(2\pi) < 0$, then we have a root $c$ in $[\pi, 2 \pi ]$. Similarly, there is a root in the interval $[2 \pi, 3 \pi]$, same argument.

Here is the subtle part: Notice that $G(0) = \int_0^0 f = 0 $. Do we consider $x=0$ to be a root of $G(x)$? is it by convention or there any underlying issues to consider here?

Im uncomfortable about it since we do not know what happes as $x \to 0^-$. Any thoughts?

Comment: indeed. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $F(0) = 0$ is a root.  You don't need to look at the limit because the function $f(x) = x \sin x$ is well-defined for all real numbers, even negative ones, and at zero; moreover, the way $F$ is defined as a definite integral from $0$ to $x$, it should be clear that $F(0) = 0$.

In fact, we can compute an *exact* antiderivative:  with the choice $$u = x, \quad du = dx, \\ dv = \sin x \, dx, \quad v = -\cos x,$$ we obtain via integration by parts
$$\int x \sin x \, dx = \int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du = -x \cos x + \int \cos x \, dx = -x \cos x + \sin x + C.$$
It follows that $$F(x) = -x \cos x + \sin x$$ for all real $x$, and $F(0) = 0$.  We have roots of $F$ whenever $x = \tan x$; this equation has no elementary closed-form solution, but it does tell us that, since $\tan x$ is periodic with period $\pi$ and is monotone increasing on each open interval $(-\pi/2 + \pi k, \pi/2 + \pi k)$ for integers $k$, that there is a unique root of $F$ in each such interval.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @heropup answered, you are looking for the zero's of function

$$F(x) = \sin (x)-x \cos (x) $$ which is an even function. For $x >0$, beside the trivial $x=0$, the roots are located closer and closet to $x_*^{(n)}=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$.

We can *approximate* these roots building Taylor series around these points and using series reversion. This gives
$$x_n= t -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{t^{2n+1}} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$ the first $a_n$'s making the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{13}{15},\frac{146}{105},\frac{781}{315},\frac{16328}{346
   5},\frac{6316012}{675675},\frac{38759594}{2027025},\frac{9655714457}{241215975},\cdots\right\}$$

Transforming the series expansion into a Padé approximant gives with a good accuracy
$$x_n=t-\frac{5 \left(24 t^4-44 t^2+9\right)}{3 t \left(40 t^4-100 t^2+47\right)}$$